# VS Code is incorrectly formatting numbers separated by apostrophes in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I am using VS Code for developing C++ code and these are my settings:

```
Editor: Format On Save: on
C_Cpp: Formatting: Default
C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback: GNU
```

This is my code before formatting:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  cout << endl;

  long large_number{ 7'958'482'164 };
  cout << "Large number: " << large_number << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is my code after formatting:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  cout << endl;

  long large_number
  {
    7 '958' 482'164 }; cout << "Large number: " << large_number << endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

Why is this happening? How can I prevent that behavior?

Comment: Try changing `Clang_format_fallback: GNU` to something different, like `LLVM`.

Comment: Thank you, i changed it to Visual Studio and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback` to a value other than `GNU`, I changed it to `Visual Studio` and it now works fine.